# Reading back HDF5 file from a different script

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am trying to learn the storage of pandas DataFrames in HDF5 format.

I am using pandas 0.17.1 on Python 3.4.3

In two Jupiter notebooks on the same directory, in `hdf5_write.ipynb` I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100,120).reshape(5,4),index=[10,11,12,13,14],columns=[20,21,22,23]) 
df
```

[image]

```
storew = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
storew['df'] = df
storew
```

[image]

```
storer = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
df2 = storer['df']
df2
```

[image]

However in the script `hdf5_read.ipynb` I can not read the hdf5 file back!:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
storer = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')
storer
```

[image: out]

The file on disk exists but it is empty. It's under my home directory, so I don't think it's a problem of permissions. Further, in my real case that leads to this test I have a large `DataFrame` for which the file is not empty but still I have a `HDF5ExtError` error when I try to read it back from an other script:
[image: out]

I already had a look at the similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591855/pandas-hdfstore-how-to-reopen), but that seems to depend on a much older pandas, while my installation is more recent. 
pd.show_version() returns :

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.4.3.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-83-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.17.1
nose: 1.3.1
pip: 1.5.4
setuptools: 3.3
Cython: None
numpy: 1.10.4
scipy: 0.13.3
statsmodels: None
IPython: 4.0.0
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: None
dateutil: 2.5.0
pytz: 2015.7
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: 3.1.1
numexpr: 2.5
matplotlib: 1.3.1
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
lxml: None
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.999
httplib2: 0.8
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: None
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
Jinja2: None
```

Comment: you need to .close() the store

Comment: @jeff: yes, I did follow the "learning pandas" book that it doesn't mention it, but it needs a call to close(). Also to be noted that if you just do not close the file even just one time, then the file remains problematic for further uses. Thank you

Comment: of course, this is like a buffered file system; further it is restricted to a single writer; see the caveats

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you store them as csv?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100,120).reshape(5,4),index=[10,11,12,13,14],columns=[20,21,22,23]) 
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Then in your second notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: ..because I am trying to learn HDF5, as we need to exchange complex data that has several df, and HDF5, if working, could be just more convenient..

Comment: Ok, my answer is off-topic then, sorry (and i don't know about HDF5, so i can't help you)